# Open BLE sensors tracking heartrate?

Tags: bluetooth, sensors, heartbeat

I have trouble finding devices from the market that send live data of heartrate via bluetooth.

Getting SDKs from big companies is a tedious task, and therefore I need just a simple device, which is possible to pair to native Android or to Unity via plugin.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Polar products will fit your needs. I recommend the Polar H7, H10 or OH1.